# 1 bit comaparator using 2x1 mux ? Create First 1 bit magnitude comparator and implement on mux?

Tags: bit, digital-design

I know What is the comparator but i don't know how to implement with Mux

Please Give Answer Of Hoe to Design 1 bit comaparator using 2x1 mux, I Create First 1 bit magnitude comparator in this we have two input A and B  And we have three output (A<B,A=B,A>B) but i don't know how implement on mux.

Answer (score 0):

To implement what you want with 2x1 MUXes, you need to implement a XOR gate:

https://vlsiuniverse.blogspot.com/2016/12/XOR-gate-using-mux.html

an AND gate:

https://vlsiuniverse.blogspot.com/2016/12/AND-gate-using-mux.html

and a NOT gate:

https://vlsiuniverse.blogspot.com/2016/12/NOT-gate-using-mux.html

Once you have those:

A==B --> NOT(A XOR B)

A>B --> NOT(B) AND A

A<B --> NOT(A) AND B